# Configurar build.gradle en proyecto eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

¡Buen día!

Tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Se puede configurar un archivo `build.gradle` dentro de un proyecto eclipse? Esto para el manejo de dependencia, algo así como `maven`.

He estado consultando este [link](http://nombre-temp.blogspot.mx/2015/11/proyectos-gradle-en-eclipse-gradle-integration.html) en el cual puedo agregar un plugin a eclipse para poder empezar a trabajar con gradle, pero no quiero crear un proyecto gradle, dado que ya tengo un proyecto (java web) y quiero manejar las dependencias con gradle.

También instale gradle en mi pc siguiendo la [documentación](https://gradle.org/install) de Gradle.

**Actualización**

Estas son las dependencias que quiero agregar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización II**

Actualmente mi gradle luce de la siguiente forma:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{

}

dependencies{

}
```

Otra de mi duda es sobre la nomenclatura a utilizar(actualmente es gradle 3.5), teniendo como referencia estás dos formas: [forma 1](http://sglora.com/tutorial-de-gradle-i/), [forma 2](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/que-es-gradle/)

**Actualización III**

Siguiendo la respuesta de Chuidiang, agregue mis dependencias faltantes y ejecute el siguiente comando con eclipse cerrado:

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:cleanEclipseClasspath
:cleanEclipseJdt
:cleanEclipseProject
:cleanEclipse
:eclipseClasspath
[Fatal Error] apache-18.pom:419:6: El destino de la instrucci¾n de procesamiento
 que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no estß permitido.
[Fatal Error] apache-18.pom:419:6: El destino de la instrucci¾n de procesamiento
 que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no estß permitido.
```

Esto hace alusión a mi pom.xml y buscando encontre a que se debe por algún carácter [no permitido](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/problema-con-xml-1136360/), además de que al ejecutar *gradle cleanEclipse eclipse* se tarda mucho en tratar de resolver las dependencias(1:30 horas).

Espero me haya explicado bien.

Gracias.

Comment: Se llama build.gradle , agrega tu archivo. Por otro lado que dependencia deseas agregar?

Comment: @Jorgesys edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

Instale mi gradle(versión 3.5) así como maven(3.5).

Después por cmd(windows) me puse en la dirección de mi proyecto hasta la altura de mi pom.xml, dónde ejecute la siguiente línea:

```
gradle init
```

Con ejecutarlo obtuve la estructura de mi projecto pero ahora con gradle, mi build.gradle tomo todas las configuraciones de mi pom.xml en automático.

[Aquí](https://gradle.org/install) pueden ver como instalar gradle en su máquina

[Aquí](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) para la instalación de Maven en su máquina.

Espero y le sirva ha alguien.

Answer (score 0):

En el fichero build.gradle añade

apply plugin: "eclipse"

y luego, desde ventana de comandos en el directorio donde esté tu proyecto y tu build.gradle, ejecuta

gradle eclipse

Eso debería crearte los ficheros propios de proyecto desde eclipse. Luego, en eclipse, simplemente "importar proyecto existente" y buscar el directorio.

Saludos.

Comment: Realice el procedimiento que indicas, ahora solo sería agregar las dependencias al build.gradle ?  Actualice mi pregunta. gracias. @Chuidiang

Comment: Si, tienes que añadir las dependencias al build.gradle, pero cada vez que toques el build.gradle, tienes que reconstruir el proyecto. Con eclipse cerrado, ejecuta "gradle cleanEclipse eclipse" y luego abre eclipse (no es necesario volver a importar)

Comment: Ok deja le intento.

Comment: actualice mi pregunta

Comment: Entre que tarda mucho y da error, posiblemente gradle  no está pudiendo acceder a internet por algún motivo y tras un rato largo con cada pom que intenta descargarse, obtiene algún tipo de página de error que no es compatible con un fichero pom. ¿Estás a través de un proxy corporativo o algo?. Busca como configurar gradle para que trabaje contra un proxy corporativo.